# Портятся данные при передаче через comport

Tags: c#, serial, port

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На передатчике строку формирую в виде стринг "\u0006\u004E\u004F\u0058\u005F и т.д.", отсылаю командой `sp.write(стринг)`. На приемнике строка меняется - в нее впихиваются какие то вопросительные знаки. Пробовал формировать массив байтов типа `byte[] dataOut = { 0x06, 0x4E, ...}` и отсылать байтами `Write(dataOut, 0, dataOut.Length)` - та же история. А мне нужно передать не текст а именно байты целенькие - в них закодированы `float` в IEEE745. Почему так и как побороть - подскажите пожалуйста?

Comment: При посылке байтов всё должно быть нормально. А как ведётся контроль? Параметры порта (baudrate и т.д.) установлены верно?

Comment: для контроля установил port.NewLine, Считываю через port.ReadLine.работаю через виртуальные ком порты, строка всегда принимается целиком и одной правильной длины . Тут явно с кодировками что то связано, это они обычно вопросительными знаками балуются. Только вот не пойму причем тут кодировки при пересылке байтов...

Comment: Причем дело явно в принимающей стороне потому что когда принимаю эту строку от прибора программой Terminal by Br@y или между двумя терминалами пересылаю- вопросительных знаков нет. А в моей программе которая должна будет принимать эту строку данные искажаются

Comment: Так принимать нужно тоже байты, а не строку. `Read(Byte[], Int32, Int32)` А то с этими юникодными строками и автоматическими преобразованиями хлопот не оберёшься: `Кодирует все символы больше 127 как (char) 63 или "?". `

Answer (score 0):

```
string Result = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(serialPort.Read(куда писать,отступ,сколько прочитать));
```

либо

```
string Result = Encoding.GetEncoding(тут подбери нужную кодировку).GetString(serialPort.Read(куда писать, отступ, сколько прочитать));
```

Comment: нет, любая кодировка имеет непечатаемые символы и встречая их она поганит данные. Вобщем только что разобрался. На передатчике строку формировать "\u0006\u004E\u004F, на приемнике получать ее только 
 массивом байтов serialport.read и ни в коем случае не readline и не readexisting. После того как из массива байтов мы выковыряли эту строку - указываем на каких позициях лежат наши IEEE754 , конвертим в массив char, из него в массив byte и из него Bitconvert в желанный float. На любом этапе слово Encoding ведет к потере данных, причем неявно - на некоторых числах это вообще незаметно

Comment: вот стоит у меня прибор и показывает 0,001 0,010 0,011 и программа показывает то же самое. Казалось бы красота. Потом прибор показывает 0,001 0,006 0,007 а программа 0,001 0,003 0,003. Таковы последствия использования кодировок